# Changing PowerPoint Layout for one page only?

Tags: interface-design, microsoft-powerpoint

How is it possible to implement multiple layouts within one PowerPoint file?

I tried following Microsoft Help article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-multiple-themes-in-one-presentation-a5648a47-1a8b-49a7-a031-23eba396ca81
Though wasn't able to set up another slide master and hence every time I changed, e.g. the layout for slide 3, every slide changed!

Comment: I'm uncertain what assistance you can get regarding this beyond "Set up a new master for a different layout". You haven't explained *why* that isn't feasible.

Comment: @Scott I looked up tutorials but I wasn't able to use two pre-made'S from the standard

Comment: Are you trying to use different *themes* or merely a different layout? If you create a new slide master you can change the layout all you want for that master. Themes are another matter entirely.

Comment: PowerPoint offers you different “layouts” or “themes” when starting a new document (with the new design change comes fonts, pictures, colors, alignment, etc.) i want to use two of these designs in one doc.

Answer (score 1):

- A "Layout" is how text and images are arranged on a slide.
- A "Theme" contains *globally* predetermined appearances within the deck, i.e. fonts, sizes, colors, images, etc.

A "theme" includes a layout, but you do not *have to have* a theme to alter any layout.

You can manually alter the *layout* of any slide to match some other "theme".

You can't "combine" themes because `Themes` specifically designate aspects of the deck. One theme will overwrite another theme. You can't tell the slides in the deck to have a red background from `Theme A` while at the same time having a blue background from `Theme B` for a few slides. Theme settings are *global*.

Merely create a new master slide and *manually alter* that slide to anything you want - change it's colors, add a background image, etc.